# Exclude specific directory/path in gradle dependency

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have an `implementation` dependency in my dependencies. The dependency has an old version of the apache commons-lang 3 dependency shaded. It is not listed as a transitive dependency of the dependency, it is just shaded. However, I require the apache commons-lang 3 dependency as well, and I need a newer version. I do not think I can just exclude the commons-lang 3 dependency as it is not transitive. Is there another way to filter out the dependency?

using gradle 7.1

Answer (score 1):

- You can check the dependency tree by using `mvn dependency:tree` to check where commons-lang is coming from and then you can exclude from the parent dependency.
- Also, Please try with providing as an external dependency of commons-lang with your newer version above its parent dependency.

Example :

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>or.apache.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang.xxx</artifactId>
        <version>newer.version</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>parent.dependency.of.commons.lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent.dependency.of.commons.lang</artifactId>
        <version>specified.version</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

try  in your 
examples:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>xxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to say I'm not using maven